# Using existing database for SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am configuring SSRS 2012 on my system. It gives an option to select/create a report server database. If I am selecting "choose an existing report server database" and selecting the database I am using for my application, I get an error "The database you selected is not a report server database...."

Why can't I use my existing database for reporting service? What are the correct steps to configure SSRS and using my existing database for creating reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database SSRS is asking for is not the database where you have data for reports, but the database where SSRS configuration and temporary datas stays.

These are the default ones:

[image: Default Databases]

If you do not have those 2 databases, let the setup create them for you.

You will create Data Sources to your database when you will create your first report.

Comment: is it okay to create custom tables within the SSRS database?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pick your own database for a report server database, the database it is referring to is the one for the reportserver application itself.

So you need to first create a report server database and link your report server to that, then the report server application will work, then inside this application you create a data source which points to your database with your data you want to report on, you can then start writing your reports.

Have a look here for more detailed steps:

[Install Reporting Services Native Mode Report Server (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143711.aspx)